# Google Translate SSL Error with Threading in Python

Tags: python, ssl, google-api, gdata, google-translate

I translating a pretty big text with google translate and to speed up the process in am calling the split up requests in threads. However, from time to time, the threads throw a SSL handshake error. What is going on?

here is the trace

```
     File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/source/graba/models.py", line 1558, in google_translate_list_strings
    service = build('translate', 'v2', developerKey='[MY DEV KEY]')
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/discovery.py", line 193, in build
    resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1588, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1336, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1014, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/Users/[PROJECT ROOT]/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 372, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 296, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:503: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Comment: My guess is that you're hammering the webserver and it looses the ability to parse all your requests at one time, or it's your network connection that drops the packets.. just a wild guess :) Seeing how you're using the native API it's strange but it's not unheard of :)

Comment: i am calling the google api, so i doubt it that (even if i try very hard) I can trouble their server with my requests :)

Comment: How many threads do you open?

Comment: Quite a few. Maybe 200, it depends on the job i am processing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, try limiting the threads to 5-20 and see if the result is the same. `while len(enumerate()) >= 5: sleep(0.1)`

Comment: The problem is that i cannot readily reproduce it all the time. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. I tested it with limited threads, and it didnt happen, but then it didnt happen without the limitation either.

Comment: As a background in networking, i'm quite positive that this is not a programmers error per se.. rather, it has to do with your bandwidth limitation (if you're running wirelessly, slow landline etc) and the way you're "hammering" the server with a few hundre threads i guess that the server simply mixed up the state of your SSL connection. On error in your thread, do a check on `conn.connect()` or `do_handshake()` and retry that step, simply recreate the socket process in the affected thread.

Comment: Are you using the free license key or do you have a paid license key? if using the free version, there is probably an upper limit to the number of 'calls' you can make in a day.  Awhile back I was in a different part of their api doing stuff and was limited to 100 API calls daily.  I found away around the limit though.